# how to calculate counts of elements of an array from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*", "%"];
var string = "2+2-3"
```

**Here count would be equal to 2**

I need to count the total no of operators used in a string

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Comment: You mean 2 elements from the string are in the array ?

Comment: it is a homework problem. i am making a calculator which should have the functionality that: ""Sequence of operations should be implemented. For example, if user enters 5 and then + and then 4 and then –, it should compute 5+4 and display 9 in the textbox/label""

Comment: i am trying to calculate the no of operators used so if that increases 2 i would scale the string by -1 and evaluate the string using (eval()

Comment: I've add in my comment the compute of total and unique operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- split the string on each char `.split("")`
- filter to keep the ones that are in the array
- take the length of the result

```js
const operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*", "%"];
var string = "2+2-3+6+6+6+6+6"

const nb_total = string.split("").filter(elt => operators.includes(elt)).length
console.log("Nb of operators", nb_total)

const nb_uni = operators.filter(elt => string.includes(elt)).length
console.log("Nb of unique operators", nb_uni)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `String.prototype.match()` can do the job:

```js
const operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*", "%"],
      string = "2+2-3",
      
      countOps = string.match(new RegExp(operators.map(o => '\\'+o).join('|'), 'g')).length

console.log(countOps)
```

Another solution could be iterating (e.g. with `Array.prototype.reduce()`) over the string and increase `countOp` counter if character is found among operators:

```js
const operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*", "%"],
      string = "2+2-3",
      countOps = [...string].reduce((r,c) => (operators.includes(c) && r++, r),0)
      
console.log(countOps)
```

Comment: `operators.includes(c) && r++, r` less complex as a single expression `(r,c) => r + Number(operators.includes(c))`. The explicit casting of the boolean is just there for convenience - not really needed, since `0 + true` would be `1` anyway but it's just more useful to be explicit.